# Why doesn't R open my saved documents any more?

Tags: r, crash

I'm not sure if this is the right forum but hoping for some help. I am running a Mac, just updated to Catalina (V10.15.6) and R version 4.0.2. The issue I will describe predates the Catalina install.

I typically save my R code as R documents on my computer. Previously, clicking on these would cause the R application to launch and the code document in question would launch alongside. However, this action now causes R to crash (or just get the neverending the spinning wheel of doom). Moreover, I cannot open these R documents even when the R application is already launched: it just makes the application crash.

Anyone got any insight into what the issue might be here? I essentially cannot use R on my Macbook at the moment which is not ideal.

Thanks for any help!
Nichola

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling R? Are you using Rstudio or just the R app?

Comment: Are you able to open your files with `File - Open file...` in RStudio or `File - Open script...` in RGui?

Comment: No idea if this is related, but there was a bug fix made for the R.app front end a few weeks ago.  See the description here:  https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-mac/2020-July/013641.html.   You can see your R.app version number in the startup banner; this bug fix was applied in version 7849.

Answer (score 0):

user2554330 is correct.   With test inputs from several of us on r-sig-mac mailing list, Simon finally was able to find a subtle bug (well, a problem caused by Apple's annoying security cruft) in R.app GUI.

I'm not sure whether the latest R-install package includes this 'fixed' version of R.app, but you can get it from the dev site, as quoted in that mail thread,

Please try the latest GUI revision 7849 from https://mac.R-project.org

Comment: Thanks this was really helpful and fixed the problem.